# Facebook Login crashes App with java.lang.ClassCastException: LoginActivity must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

Tags: java, android, android-studio, facebook-android-sdk

I am new to Android and I am following the Facebook SDK guide ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.0 )

**Here is everything, please attempt to run before answering**: https://github.com/fabianhjr/devf-android/tree/facebook-login

Here is LoginActivity:

```
package mx.devf.androidassistant;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private FacebookFragment facebookFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            facebookFragment = new FacebookFragment();
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(android.R.id.content, (Fragment) facebookFragment)
                    .commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            facebookFragment = (FacebookFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(android.R.id.content);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to run the code I have, I get the following trace

```
07-12 12:56:53.220  17178-17178/com.fabiahjr.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fabiahjr.myapplication, PID: 17178
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.fabiahjr.myapplication/mx.devf.androidassistant.LoginActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: mx.devf.androidassistant.LoginActivity@655a9a18 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: mx.devf.androidassistant.LoginActivity@655a9a18 must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener
            at mx.devf.androidassistant.FacebookFragment.onAttach(FacebookFragment.java:86)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:898)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2157)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
```

Comment: Why are you using FacebookFragment? Please see the javadocs in that class: "This class is package private, and is not intended to be consumed by external applications." DO NOT use FacebookFragment. The article you linked to does not use FacebookFragment.

Comment: Create a new class named MainFragment that's a subclass of the Fragment class.

I named it FacebookFragment instead of MainFragment.(It isn't the FacebookFragment you are refering to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> LoginActivity must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener

The solution is in the title of your question. Your Activity has to implement `OnFragmentInteractionListener`.

```
public class LoginActivity extends FragmentActivity
     implements FacebookFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener{

// implement methods of the interface here
```

**Addition:**

Take a look at the source of `FacebookFragment`:

```
/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link FacebookFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link FacebookFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
```

You should use `newInstance`, instead of no-arg constructor.

Comment: Error:(20, 59) error: cannot find symbol class OnFragmentInteractionListener I think I have already tried that. :| I don't know if it has aything to do with the support library or any other imports.

Comment: try this way: FacebookFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener

Comment: Error:(20, 8) error: cyclic inheritance involving FacebookFragment

Comment: This is what I have in OnFragmentInteractionListener     public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

Comment: I have no idea how you managed to make cyclic inheritance:) Try to clean your project, and if that won't help, post more details on that error.

Comment: I had tried cleaning, I am going to push to the git repo in a second.

Comment: You have to implement the interface in LoginActivity, not in FacebookFragment. See my updated answer.

Comment: You can use this: 
https://github.com/sromku/android-simple-facebook

This is super easy to use.